# Why can't I use a <script> tag for jQuery anywhere?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is an issue of scope I believe. I wish to use jQuery in a Joomla module and include the code within a  tags in the php source. This works:

```
<script> alert("foo"); </script>
```

but this doesn't:

```
<script> alert($.jquery); alert(jQuery.jquery); </script>
```

which should produce at least 1 alert box with the jQuery version, but the alert says "undefined". The webpage `<head>` section already includes jQuery, and it is used in the html stream before the above `<script>`. I don't believe the `<script>` block defines a new, independent script scope / context, but that is how it behaves.

Comment: have u tried jQuery only inplace of jQuery.jquery

Comment: Can you include the jquery `<script ...>` tag?

Comment: You'd generally check for jQuery with `typeof jQuery` and see that it returns `function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want version you need

`jQuery.fn.jquery`

Comment: the .fn. was missing. `$` isn't defined, perhaps no-conflict was called earlier, but jQuery.fn.jquery produced the version string. Thanks for the quick replies. This my first use of Stk Ex, so I can't vote yet, but this would get it if I could.

Comment: likely true about noConflict() in joomla

Comment: @user4830534 Then, you may want to accept the answer that best addresses your issue, by clicking on its corresponding checkmark.

Answer (score 3):

Add `.fn.`:

```
alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);
// or
alert($.fn.jquery);
```

Or try using jQuery as a function:

```
alert(jQuery().jquery);
// or short:
alert($().jquery);
```

Michael pointed out another one:

```
alert(jQuery.prototype.jquery);
// so we can also add
alert($.prototype.jquery);
```

### If you want your code to work:

```
// add somewhere before:
jQuery.extend(jQuery, {jquery: jQuery.fn.jquery});

// Than this should work just fine:
alert(jQuery.jquery);
alert($.jquery);
```

Extend JQuery object (`$` or `jQuery`) by `.jquery` equal to `jQuery.fn.jquery`.

**As you can see we can add any properity to jQuery.** Let's do `jQuery.version`:

```
$.extend($,{version:$().jquery});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do
`jQuery.fn.jquery`

You can also do
`jQuery.prototype.jquery`

Comment: Ostensibly, you could get the version number by using `jQuery.jquery` if you first instantiated a new jQuery object by using  `jQuery = new jQuery()`